# Match all strings from list A to every strings from list B

Tags: python, compare, match

I am looking for help in writing a script (preferably python), to compare two lists. The task:

I have list of filenames in file a.txt:
Example:

```
ABC
BCD
DEF
EDC
```

and a strings list in list b.txt:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
```

what I want script to do is "compare" those two lists and output result to file result.txt, where I can have every string from list a next to all matches of list b.txt so, for example, result.txt would look like for the above lists:

```
ABC|A,B,C
BCD|B,C,D
DEF|D,E,F
EDC|E,D,C
```

I might add, both lists are quite big, list a has 60k rows, list b few k.

Would appreciate the help a lot! thanks

Comment: Where's the problem exactly? Are you stuck at reading in a file, when trying to find substrings, or .... ?

Comment: Oh, sorry if I wsnt clear enough, Im basically new to python, so I have no clue how to write this at all :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Build lists `A_list`, `B_list` from datafiles
2. Write the result file looping over the filenames (`a`) provided by first list (`A_list`)

   - build the `matches` list of the elements (`b`) of the second list (`B_list`) that are in the `a` element
   - optionally skip the end of the loop if filenames with no match are not needed
   - write the result line for filename joining the matches

```
with open("a.txt", 'r') as f:
    A_list = f.read().splitlines()
with open("b.txt", 'r') as f:
    B_list = f.read().splitlines()
    
with open('result.txt', 'w') as f:
    for a in A_list:
        matches = [b for b in B_list if b in a]
        if not matches: continue  # optional
        f.write(f"{a}|{','.join(matches)}\n")
```